# Creating popular mobile app menu/action bar effect in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, mobile, interface-design

I see this line effect in a lot of mobile apps. It looks pretty nice. How can I recreate this effect in Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a green background
- Draw the 2 lines with line tool
- Double-click on the line layer
- Apply `bevel emboss > pillow emboss (select from dropdown)`
- Rasterize both line layers
- Select marquee tool > fade from top > and then delete the bottom part of the line layer, apply this on both layers

You can follow these screenshots, I tried to explain this as easy/best as I can.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My output : I reduced its opacity to 55% you can use 100% or anything to make it look more appealing ....

[image]

Hope this will help

Comment: Alternatively if you're using layer styles you can use the "gradient overlay" to create that fade-out effect on the bottom in tandem using the blending modes.

Comment: yes another way to avoid marquee fade option..

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

1. Make a new layer.
2. Make a Black line with Line Tool in that layer. Put Fill Pixels setting on
   so you can deselect anti-aliasing.
3. Go to that layers Blending Options.

   - Add Drop Shadow Blend Mode:
     Overlay.
   - Color: White.
   - Angle: 180 or 0.
   - Distance: 1px.
   - Spread: 0%. Size: 0px.
     Noise: 0px.
   - Make sure that "Layer knocks out drop shadow" is selected.
   - You might
     want to set opacity down a bit as well.
4. From above Drop Shadow in the "Bleding options: Default" Set Blend
   Mode: Overlay. Set fill to match the white drop shadow. Then adjust
   the Opacity above to give both of the lines a general opacity. ( And when I say match, I mean so that it looks good.. )
5. For the "fade to transparent" look, I would use Eraser tool with
   Soft Round Brush that of course has hardness 0 if that isn't clear
   enough. ( Or Layer mask and do same thing with Brush Tool and Black
   color. )